# Best practice: GCF with Firebase call within or GCF and after that Firebase call

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

First of all, I don't know how to measure the performance of these two options, this is why I am asking openly if someone has evaluated/encountered this situation and how they proceeded and why.

**Context** From Flutter I am calling a GCF to do some operations in Python. After calling this function, some of the data retrieved is being used to update a Firebase Document.

What is better (or what pros and cons) has the following 2 scenarios:

- **Scenario 1** Adding to my GCF the code necessary to update the Firebase Document
- **Scenario 2** Keeping in GCF only the function and writing to Firebase from Flutter using a Firestore.instance widget

I would be inclined towards Scenario 2 due to structure of the code, readability and possible separation of functions, but could there be any performance handicap of doing so or any other issue I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of total performance, I don't see that there is a significant difference between the two, for only the work you're describing.  If anything #2 will be a bit slower since it requires two round trips between client and server, but for a single document, I wouldn't worry about that.  You really should benchmark these things if you're deeply concerned.

The main practical difference between the two is that the second choice will store the updated document in the local cache so that it's available for subsequent queries while the app is offline.